# Why google.us url get reverted to google.co.in any solution to visit US?

Tags: url, routes, server, bridge

- >     [> Actually google.uk, google.as.. works fine?][1]

> [1]: http://google.us

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this problem and found this useful:

Just add "/ncr" as suffix in URL

For e.g,

http://www.google.com/ncr = google.com

http://www.google.co.in/ncr = google.co.in

Comment: no not exactly .com works I know that I am asking how to enter inside .us and ncr results back to India. (server reverts back to india)